# How to properly use a java substring in an if test?

Tags: java, if-statement, substring

I'm reading a file line-by-line with Java and parsing the data in each line for a report. Periodically, there will be a URL that's been written to a line, and I want to bypass that line. I need to set up an `if...then` that tests for the presence of a URL -- in this specific case, I define that as the first four bytes of the line reading `http`. If the condition is true, read the next line in the file, but if the condition is false, send the current line to the parser for report output.

Simple, no? I'm running into issues where I cannot get my `if..then` statement to accurately recognize a `true` condition. My only clue is that when my `inputString` is **equal** to the test value, it passes as `true`. Beyond that...I can't spot anything out of the ordinary.

```
public class testClass
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String inputString1 = "http://www.google.com/r";
        String inputString2 = "google";
        String inputString3 = "google search";
        String inputString4 = "http";
        parseInput(inputString1);
        parseInput(inputString2);
        parseInput(inputString3);
        parseInput(inputString4);
    }
    //
    private static void parseInput(String inputString8) {
        int httpFlag;
        if (inputString8.substring(0,4) == "http") 
            { httpFlag = 1467; } else
            { httpFlag = 10644; }
        System.out.println(inputString8+" "+inputString8.toLowerCase().substring(0,4)+" "+httpFlag); 
     } 
}
```

Here's my output:

```
http://www.google.com/r http 10644
google goog 10644
google search goog 10644
http http 1467
```

I am expecting `1467` for both `inputString1` and `inputString4`. 
The console *appears* to display my input and substring properly, and nothing in the Java Documentation suggests that my substring would be a `char` array or anything apart from a string, so I can't figure out why `http` as the first four bytes of a 4-byte string is "different" from the first four bytes of a (4+x)-byte string. What am I missing?

Comment: To compare `String` use its `equals` method.

Comment: If i had a nickel every time someone was comparing Strings with the wrong way in this site , well you know how it goes.

Comment: There should be a close reason specifically for it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis No, literally a close reason that says "Closed because that's not how you compare Strings in Java" ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `if (inputString8.substring(0,4).equals("http"))`.

`==` operator checks if the two expressions are the same object, you want to check if they have the same value.

Comment: Thanks for the useful differentiation about why one works and the other doesn't! That helps.

Answer (score 5):

Compare strings with `equals`, not `==`. There's nothing special about the fact the string you're comparing is the result of calling `substring`.

Comment: I believe this is correct. Most of the time == will give you the correct answer, but I've encountered a couple instances when it will not. Its just safer to use equals.. or better yet StringUtils.equals.

Comment: @dwwilson66 Why did you choose to use `=` and not `==` as stated?

Comment: Use the method "equals" not the operator "="

Comment: Single = is assignment operator wilson not comparison.

Comment: @Billman "safety" is not involved here. You may want to read the answers to the question this will be closed as a dup of; it works "sometimes" because string literals are pooled (interned / flyweight pattern) and you have two references to the same object, which is what `==` compares.

Comment: @Brian.. thanks, yes I'm familiar with why it sometimes works, but I thought that if he didn't understand the difference between = and equals, then telling him about interned strings was only going to confuse him more.

Comment: @BillMan: *"Most of the time == will give you the correct answer..."* No, that's not even close to correct. Most of the time, `==` will give you the **wrong** answer. Moreover, the *last* thing you want as an engineer is something that's correct *most* of the time.

Comment: @BillMan Sorry, but your original comment contradicts your "familiarity". *"Most of the time == will give you the correct answer, but I've encountered a couple instances when it will not"*. You don't "encounter" instances when it's not unless you're doing it wrong. Which is to say, using `==`. `==` does exactly one thing; compares reference values. If you want to know if one `String` contains the same text as another `String` you use `.equals()`. If you want to know if two references point to the same object, you use `==`

Comment: I agree with you guys. Precise language matters. I did not use it.

Answer (score 1):

== tests to see if two things are the same object. If you want to compare strings char by char use the equals () method of the String class.